# Remove sidebar lines in Blogger custom template

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm using a free custom Blogger template for my little recipe blog, and I wanted to change the widths of the main column and right sidebar to accommodate my Adsense ads. However, after I finally figured out how to do this, the left sidebar border is all wonky, and the deco lines separating the posts in the main column now appear off-center (I tried to post a screen shot of this but I can't because I'm new). Anyway, I feel like a ding-a-ling because I've spent an hour trying to figure out how to fix this.

My site is http://www.economicaleats.com/. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: can you show some code, file names that you have change or process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your css file, and search for `#content-wrapper`

This is your content-wrapper css:

```
#content-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px;
    background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NbCNAsqNcgQ/UXmDtvpfLiI/AAAAAAAACOU/QUMfz2qa5vQ/s000/content-bg.png) repeat-y 0 15px;
}
```

Remove the background tag and it will be fixed.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Do you have any suggestions for centering the lines between posts? I would like to keep them, but there's that little deco thing in the center that appears to be off center now.

Comment: @HeatherL You mean you want the posts to be centered? And if it did work, please press on the big blank V in the left of my answer, to approve it

Comment: Done! I'm actually referring to the lines separating the posts. There is a line with a decorative swirl between each one, and since I adjusted the column widths, the swirl has shifted off center. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. The lines separate the post excerpts in the main column.

Comment: @HeatherL on my screen it looks fine. Could you send me a screenshot?